# Accessing sibling method

Tags: php, oop

I've been searching for an answer all day, but I can't seem to find one. Sorry if I don't make much sense, I'm losing my mind over this.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
abstract class Parent {
    abstract public function Test();
}
class Child1 extends Parent {
    abstract public function Test() {
        echo "Test!";
    }
}
class Child2 extends Parent {
    public function Test2() {
        echo "Test2!";
        $this->Test(); // Child1::Test();
    }
}
```

Again, sorry if I'm not making much sense. I will try to explain more if you need me to.

Comment: You haven't actually said what you _are_ trying to do. Neither of your child classes will work though, since for `Child1` you've left the `Test` method abstract, and in `Child2` you've not overridden it, so it remains abstract. Neither can be instantiated, as a result.

Comment: If you want `Child1` to be creatable, remove the `abstract` keyword inside this class, and that one will work. We'll probably need more detail for the second child.

Comment: Run it and read the errors..

Comment: The first error is `Cannot use 'Parent' as class name as it is reserved`

Comment: Inside `Test2()` you would have to create the other child, assuming you make `Test()` not abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you're tryning to do has no sense in OOP. If you want to execute `Test()` from the first Child, you need to move the function in the parent.

**EDIT:** Well, I'm going to be more comprehensive:

You're trying to call a function of another child, which have only the parent class in common. `Child1` and `Child2` are as close as `String` and `Integer` can be in Java (or any other OOP language). Imagine that you called `.upper()` function on a int: it doesn't make sense.

Comment: And this makes no sense as an answer ;)

Comment: Well, unless you make some weird assumptions, there's no better response in my opinion. He's trying to call a function of another class which is impossible...

Answer (score 1):

It's not an OOP pattern, and not available in any OOP language that I kow of (except for introspection magic):
Child2 do not know anything (and does not have to) about Child1 class. they could be defined independently.

I think that at this point you should explain what your needs are. I guess we could help you ,with some design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the concept of abstract classes and methods.

#### Abstract classes

Abstract classes are classes that define some basic behavior and cannot be instantiated. They are designed to be subclassed.

#### Abstract methods

These are methods that need to be implemented by the extending class. Like interfaces abstract methods define behavior without an implementation.

#### Your code

In your code you declared an abstract class with an abstract method.

```
abstract class Parent {
    public abstract function Test();
}
```

When another class subclasses `Parent` it must implement the abstract method making it concrete.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    public function Test() {
        echo "Test!";
    }
}
```

#### Accessing sibling method

A class or instance has no concept of a sibling. A class cannot know who subclasses its parent and access it in a static way.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here:

- `Parent` is a reserved word
- `Child1` contains an abstract method, so it can't contain a body.
- `Child2` extends `Parent`, but doesn't implement the `Test()` method.

As a result, none of this will instantiate. Child2() should probably extend Child1(),(or implement the `Test()` method itself). Correct these problems, fix any other errors that PHP might tell you about then this:

```
$p = new Child2();

$p->Test2();
```

Should give you this:

```
Test2!Test!
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Test` overrided function in `Child1` *should not* be abstract (as you are defining it). To call the `Test` function of `Child1` from the `Test2` function of `Child2` use:

```
Child1 foo = new Child1();
echo foo->Test();
```

Thing you can do only because it's been defined as *public*, not because `Child1` and `Child2` have any relationship.