# Access to functions from extended classes

Tags: php, class

I have a parent class and two classes that are extending it. The question is how to call a function from one extended class that is in other extended class?

code is below:

```
    // PARENT CLASS
class Controller {
    function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->db = new Database(); // WORKS FINE
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('Database connection could not be established.');
        }
    }
}
class Api extends Controller { 
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function RenderForm() { 
        // from here I want to call function that is inside Forms class
    }
}

class Forms extends Controller { 
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function ReturnForm() { 
        $this->db->query("SOME QUERY");

        // code here builds a form for output and stores it as $HTML;

        return $HTML;

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing sibling method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046992/accessing-sibling-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to make an instance of the `forms` class like so:

```
class Api extends Controller { 

    function RenderForm() { 
       $form = new Forms(); //Create instance of your forms class
       $form->ReturnForm(); //Use function from your forms class

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, `function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }` is completely redundant.

Comment: @Shogunivar thanks, i used like `$form->ReturnForm();` and forgot to create instance

Comment: @Narf i wrote this script few years ago, now doing some updates, thanks for info ;)

Comment: @PhAbd Happends to the best of us